# CSS transform scale increase also div parent body

Tags: html, css

I have a problem in formatting an anchor link using the transform scale attributes when hovering on it.

I have a link inside a div (that div is used to alight the link to the right), and i would like to enlarge when I hover on it. However, when i do it, it also increase the body size of the parent div, thus moving all my other elements on the page. Why that happens? As far as I know scale should not act on the size of the elements, least of all on its parent.

Can you tell me where I'm wrong. I'm quite new to html and css, so maybe i completely set up bad my code.

Thanks to anyone who can help me.

```css
a#fonte1 {
    font-size: 1rem !important;
    font-weight: 300 !important;
    transition: transform 0.2s ease !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
  }

a#fonte1:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2) !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
    color: rgb(13,89,253) !important;
    border: 1px solid rgb(13,89,253) !important;
    border-radius: 0.3rem !important;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="showcase border-bottom">
    <div class="container-fluid p-0">
        <div class="row g-0">
            <div class="col-lg-6 order-lg-2">
                ...
                        </div>  
            <div class="col-lg-6 order-lg-1 ">
                <h2>[title 1]</h2>
                            <p class="mb-0" style = "text-align: justify">
                    ...
                            </p>
                            <div style="text-align:right;">
                    <a id="fonte1" href="#">
                        Link
                    </a>
                </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
                <div class="row g-0">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 ">
                            ...
                        </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 ">
                            <h2>[title 2]</h2>
                            <p class="mb-0" style = "text-align: justify">
                                    ...
                            </p>
                        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: So, Can you give the child div a class and do the hover?

Comment: @Paulie_D: thanks, i changed it, anyway the problem remains;

Comment: @Daniel Dominic: if i do like this, it scales all the div and so the link text goes out of the border (i.e. it is not aligned anymore with the above paragraph when i hover).

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm sorry, I know you're trying to help me, and I'm not doing my best, but I tried to create a snippet trough JSFiddle, but I didn't achieve to reproduce the problem. I should import all the bootstrap part, but that would make the snippet surely not "minimal".

Comment: @Paulie_D Ok thanks you very much, I did manage to edit my original post with a snippet reproducing the problem. As you can see, when i hover onto "link", the elements below are moved down.

Comment: decrease using of `!important` its very bad practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding a border on hover which changes the size of the element. Add a transparent border on the base state and change its color on hover.

```css
a#fonte1 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

a#fonte1:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgb(13, 89, 253);
  border: 1px solid rgb(13, 89, 253);
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="showcase border-bottom">
  <div class="container-fluid p-0">
    <div class="row g-0">
      <div class="col-lg-6 order-lg-2">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 order-lg-1 ">
        <h2>[title 1]</h2>
        <p class="mb-0" style="text-align: justify">
          ...
        </p>
        <div style="text-align:right;">
          <a id="fonte1" href="#">
                        Link
                    </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row g-0">
      <div class="col-lg-6 ">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 ">
        <h2>[title 2]</h2>
        <p class="mb-0" style="text-align: justify">
          ...
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you very very much Paulie, you have been really helpful. I solved.